Elasticsearch Custom Analyzer and Results Scoring
I am trying to apply some custom analyzer (checked one out called Porter Stemming) from the ES website, and it seems I could maybe use it.
I would like to search documents with the following results priority:

Any partial matches with the stemmed results
Any exact match with the input query.

I have added the custom analyzer here:
    "setting": {
      "similarity": {
        "default": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "porter_stem_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "porter_stem"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "porter_stem": {
            "type": "porter_stem"
          }
        }
      }
    }

Similarly, inside my properties, I have added the custom analyzer I created above:
      "properties":{
        "name": {
          "type": "search_as_you_type",
          "fields":{
            "raw":{
              "type":"keyword"         
            },
            "normalize":{
              "type":"keyword",
              "normalizer":"lowercase"            
            },
            "english":{
              "type":"text",
              "analyzer":"english"            
            },
            "word_count":{
              "type":"token_count",
              "analyzer":"standard"            
            },
            "porter_stem":{
              "type":"text",
              "analyzer":"porter_stem_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },

I would like to know get search results using the name field, for example:
If the input is 'apples', then stem result will be 'appl', and I would like to prioritize search results of 'apple', then 'apples'.
I guess the main point is how to apply this stemming to my property to be able to search with stemming applied!
